# Finding the specific index of a list of large array

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I have a list of large array of different lengths. I want to find the position of each array larger than 420. For example, [size=(134,7),size=(620,7), size=(800,7),......]

My code is below

```
for x in x_train:
       if len(x)>420:
           print(x_train.index(x))
```

I got this error:

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an 
error in the future.
```

What will be the correct solution?

Comment: Please show full stacktrace and/or ensure this will reproduce with this minimal code. Looks like deprecation from other code or internals of your libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a warning that something has been deprecated, but is not an error. I highly doubt your code block produced this warning, and chances are some imported library or other code was the cause.

Anyways, about your code, it is extremely inefficient, as once you find `x` you are looking for it again in the list. Use `enumerate` to get the index instead:

```
for i, x in enumerate(x_train):
    if len(x) > 420:
        print(i)
```

With a list comprehension, you can store all of the indexes:

```
indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(x_train) if len(x) > 420]
```

Comment: Whenever the index is going to be needed, use `enumerate`. It's very costly to call `.index()` actually, so instead of trying to find the index each time, you can include it when you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use List comprehension to solve it.

```
#Create a sample list of arrays of arbitrary length.
myList = [np.full((134,7), 10), np.full((620,7),0), np.full((800,7),0), np.full((150,7),0), np.full((500,7),0)]

indexes_gt_420 = [i for i in range(len(myList)) if len(myList[i]) > 420]
indexes_gt_420
     [1, 2, 4]
```